# Passing value from textbox to controller as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, parameter-passing

So in my View I need a simple textbox like so:

```
 <input type="text" name="CVR" placeholder="Enter CVR" required />
```

in the same view, at the end I have the submit button:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "SendMail", new { studentId = Html.ViewData.Model.StudentId, companyId = Html.ViewData.Model.CompanyId, applicationId = Html.ViewData.Model.ApplicationId, companyCVR = Model.CVR})
```

The data works, until the "companyCVR = Model.CVR". I am having trouble changing "companyCVR" to the text the user inputs in the textbox above.

This is my controller constructor:

```
public ActionResult SendMail(string studentId, string companyId, int applicationId, string companyCVR)
```

and technically, this should work:

```
contract.CVR = companyCVR;
```

It works when I hardcoded (contract.CVR = "12345"). My problem is passing the value from the textbox to companyCVR which I am trying to pass as a parameter to the controller.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're wanting companyCVR to be assigned the value entered by the user in the browser and for that to happen while the the page is in the browser?

Comment: Yes. When clicking submit it should take that value and pass it to the controller. Not sure what you meant by "while the page is in the browser" ?

Comment: I mean for that assignment to occur without the server being involved in any way.

Comment: I am not sure if is required. Also am not sure how I can assign the value properly, like I did with the other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be easier if you use a `<form>`. Something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "Contract", null, FormMethod.Post), new { id = "myForm" })
{
     <input type="hidden" value=@Html.ViewData.Model.StudentId name="studentId" />
     <input type="hidden" value=@Html.ViewData.Model.CompanyId name="companyId" />
     <input type="hidden" value=@Html.ViewData.Model.ApplicationId name="applicationId" />
     <input type="text" name="companyCVR" />

}

<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="$('#myForm').submit();" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it a bit (you did not mention the controller) but now it works! Now I would just like to know if I can put the submit button at the end of the page ? do I have to put everything in the form? I have a page worth of static text after this textbox :)

Comment: You can change the button to <input type="button" onclick="$('#formId').submit();" />

Comment: How can I add an ID to the form?

Comment: Forgot to mention. You have to add a refernce for jquery and add an Id to the form.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "Contract", null, FormMethod.Post), new { id = "yourId" })

Comment: Ok I needed the line like this:  @using (Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "Contract", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "cvr" }))